# Can I disable pointer events on a container but still allow it to be scrolled with the mouse?

Tags: css

I think the answer is no and thus I'm going to need a new approach.

Essentially what I'm trying to do is put a group of floating action buttons on top of a leaflet map. There may be a lot of buttons and thus I want to allow the user to scroll through them. So I put the fabs into a container to allow them to be scrollable but this then prevents mouse events from reaching the underlining map.

Does anyone know a way I can allow the containers to be scrollable but not prevent mouse events from reaching the background?

Here's the basic set up I've got:

```html
<div class="container">
  <div id="map"></div>

  <div class="controls">
    <button class="fab">Button</button>
    ...
  </div>
</div>
```

```css
.container {
  position: relative;
}

#map {
  position: absolute;
  inset: 0;
}

.controls {
  overflow: auto;
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  top: 0;
  bottom: 0;
}
```

and [here's a codepen](https://codepen.io/rebeccastevens-the-decoder/pen/dydXBwx) that shows the problem I've got.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It can be done with the [:has pseudo selector](https://drafts.csswg.org/selectors-4/#has-pseudo).

```css
.scroll-area:not(:has(:hover)) {
  pointer-events: none;
}
```

This selector hasn't been rolled out to all browsers yet though ([caniuse.com/css-has](https://caniuse.com/css-has)) but there is a [postcss plugin](https://github.com/csstools/postcss-plugins/tree/main/plugins/css-has-pseudo).